# Reverting git reset

Tags: git, git-reset

I was on a feature branch with changes committed but not pushed. I wanted to run the code as it existed a few weeks back so I ran `git reset --soft xxxxx`, followed by `git reset --hard`. I foolishly didn't consider that I had changes made. They were committed so they should at least be recoverable, right? I just need to know how to find the commit hash I guess. Any help?

Comment: No worries. Check your `HEAD` reflog with a simple `git reflog`. An alternative would be to check directly the specific reflog of that branch with `git reflog <branchName>` which will only list previous positions of that branch tip, not all previous `HEAD` positions (possibly more noisy)

Comment: @RomainValeri awesome, thanks. That was a stressful few moments worrying I may have just lost a week's work!

Comment: The reflog is your friend, if it got committed recently it'll probably be in the reflog (until git does it's gc and packing). If you committed it at some point, you can probably get back to it even if you then reset it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-reset%5D+undo+reset+%22--hard%22